# Interesting solution to animal problem

Tags: problem-solving, word-problem

There are some chickens and some cows. There are 35 heads and 110 feet. How many chickens and cows are there?

Recently I saw a solution that did the following:

110/2 = 55

55 - 35 = 20

Hence there are 20 cows and 15 chickens. But why does the following method work? I can't seem to understand the intuition behind it, how do we prove this method will always work?

Comment: **Partial Thoughts:** Suppose we think of cows as two individual beings, with $1/2$ head and $2$ legs each.

So, we have some number $A$ of chickens, and some number $B$ of half-cows. 

We know that, no matter what, each will have the same number of legs. Hence, $110/2 = 55$ tells us that, in total, $A+B=55$: there are $55$ chickens and half-cows.

Comment: This justifies a perspective on the first calculation, but I'm not sure how to frame things properly for the second one. My thought at the moment is that they decided to subtract off the number of whole heads, and it just so happened to work out in a sensible way, but maybe there's a deeper reason I'm overlooking.

Comment: @PrincessEev  Dividing $ \ 110 \ $ by two gives $ \ 55 \ $ "bipeds", as you suggested,  But there are only $ \ 35 \ $ heads, so the first calculation gives " $ 20 \ $ heads too many".  The  $ \ 20 \ $ "excess heads" means we have "over-counted" one head for each cow.  The rest of the $ \ 35 \ $ heads belong to the chickens.  (We can then check that $ \ 20·4 \ + \ 15·2 \ = \ 110 \ $ legs.)

Answer (score 1):

It will always work. Let number of cows and chickens $x$ and $y$ respectively.

using legs $4x+2y=110$ (dividing by 2)

$2x +y=55$

using heads $x+y=35$

their difference $x=20$ gives number of cows.

When $110$ is dividing by $2$, it is assuming that each cow as a chicken. But actually the number cows is twice that number since number of cow's leg is twice number of chicken's legs.
That's why $55-35=20$ gives number of cows.